# Typescript type any[] but of one type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to have a type `any[]`, but all to be of the same type? i.e.

```
// Allow
const f1: any[] = [1, 2, 3];
const f2: any[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// Disallow cause we have both number and string
const f3: any[] = [1, 2, 'a'];
```

Comment: You could take a look at generics or just explicitly specify the type. Something like: `Array<number | string>`, but this would not enforce every element to be of the same type, just that elements can be either numbers or strings.

Comment: No, I specifically want to allow `any` but I want the array to be of the same type for all of its arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do that without specifying the type. Maybe if you could provide a specific use case and considering other possible solutions to shaping up the data?

Comment: No you can not. `any` basically says "I do not care what this is", so what you want to achieve is not possible in that way. Maybe provide more information on what you use case is.

Comment: You can also add, if you want, a check function which makes sure your elements all have the same type

Answer (score 0):

I think there is misunderstanding of `any` type.

First of all let define what is [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) type. From documentation:

> We may need to describe the type of variables that we do not know when we are writing an application. These values may come from dynamic content, e.g. from the user or a 3rd party library. In these cases, we want to opt-out of type checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks.

So with `any` type we tell to the compiler to not check types and just pass them thru.

If we want to make type check when compiling, we should specify type we want. From your example, types of `f1` and `f2` are known at compile time.

```
var f1 = new Array<string>(0);
f1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];  // OK
f1 = [1, 2, 'a'];  // Type error

var f2 = new Array<number>(0);
f2 = [1, 2, 3];  // OK
f2 = [1, 2, 'a'];  // Type error
```

Or do even simplier

```
var f3 = [1, 2, 3]; // Now f3 is of type number[]
f3 = [1, 2, 'a'];  // Type error
```

Result: remove `any[]` from you code and you get what you want.